# In C++, (how) can I make a local variable available in other classes during the lifetime of this variable

Tags: c++, scope, singleton

I am writing a DLL that does chemical calculations. At the entry point (let's say a method called `entryPoint()`), I get the number of chemical components (`componentCount`) participating in the reaction and their input concentrations as an array with length `componentCount`.
To define the reactions, I use a `Component` enum, which (using operator overloading) enables me to write things like `Component::H + Component::O2 >> Component::H2O` to define a reaction.

To actually calculate the reaction results, I need to map each enum to the index in the `concentrations` array. This mapping is not static, but defined by the program calling my DLL and can change between calls to the entry point.
I created a `ComponentMapping` class which can calculate the mapping (using UUIDs) and then provides a `int index(Component)` and a `Component component(int)` member function.

My **Problem** is, that I need to use this mapping in a lot of places during the runtime of the `entryPoint()` function. Normally I would write something like this

```cpp
void entryPoint(int componentCount, double[] concentrations) {
  // somewhat expensive instanciation, which uses UUIDs to generate mapping
  ComponentMapping mapping{componentCount};
  
  Reaction reaction1{mapping, Component::H + Component::O2 >> Component::H2O};
  // and so on...
}
```

passing the mapping to anything that needs it. However, like I said, I need to use the mapping in a lot of places and always passing it to every instance and function that uses it  somewhere down the call chain would be very tedious.

So what I would like is the ability to make that mapping available in other contexts. Of course I could just use a singleton, but this means I (and especially also other devs working on the same project) need to remember to update the mapping at the beginning of each entry point (there are multiple). Is there any alternative or modification of the singleton pattern which scopes the lifetime of the mapping to that of the `entryPoint()` function?

Comment: "passing it to every instance and function that uses it somewhere down the call chain would be very tedious." This line of thought leads to globals and spaghetti code. You may not like it but passing it to every instance and function that uses it is the opposite of tedious on the long run

Comment: I probably would have posted this below any other question than mine too and I don't like the idea of global variables either...
And if I don't find a good alternative I will probably go the route of passing down everything, but I hoped there might be a good in-between alternative

Comment: a somewhat in between strategy is to redesign methods that require *something* to be methods of a class and the *something* is a member of that class.

Comment: I would take a step back and ask myself whether the responsibilities could be redistributed. (It looks a bit weird that the expression `Component::H + Component::O2 >> Component::H2O`, of some undisclosed type, apparently represents a reaction, but then there is a `Reaction` class as well.)

Comment: @molbdnilo a Reaction has more parameters than just the [stoichiometric components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoichiometry), which are repsresented by the `H + O2 >> H2O` expression, that's why there is a separate class.
@463035818_is_not_a_number I like the idea, however this would mean putting a whole lot of classes which are nicely separated at the moment into a single big class which also would not increase readability/maintainability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came up with my own solution, in case anyone is interested:
I created a `LifetimeScope` class, which can be used to initialize temporarily scoped Singletons and looks as follows:

```cpp
class LifetimeScope {
public:
  LifetimeScope() = default;
  LifetimeScope(const LifetimeScope&) = delete;
  LifetimeScope(LifetimeScope&&) = delete;
  LifetimeScope& operator=(const LifetimeScope&) = delete;
  LifetimeScope& operator=(LifetimeScope&&) = delete;

  ~LifetimeScope() {
    for (auto& f : m_onScopeEndFunctions) {
      f();
    }
  }  
  
  void onScopeEnd(void (*f)()) {
    m_onScopeEndFunctions.push_back(f);
  }

private:
  std::vector<void (*)()> m_onScopeEndFunctions;
```

Now Singleton classes (e.g. the `ComponentMapping`) can look like this:

```cpp
class ComponentMappipng {
public:
  void destroy() {
    delete m_instance;
    m_instance = nullptr;
  }

  void create(LifetimeScope& scope) {
    assert(!s_instance);
    s_instance = new ComponentMapping();
    scope.onScopeEnd(destroy);
  }

  ComponentMapping& instance() {
    assert(s_instance);
    return *s_instance;
  }

  // instance methods

private:
  // instance fields
  static ComponentMapping* s_instance;
}
```

The entry point then looks like this:

```cpp
void entryPoint() {
  LifetimeScope scope();
  ComponentMapping::create(scope);

  // stuff that uses the componentMapping
}
```

At the end of the function, the componentMapping will be distroyed, so it cannot be accidentally used in an invalid scope.

Answer (score 0):

I see three solutions here:

1. As you said to just pass it forward everywhere
2. Use a global variable defined at the begging
3. Pass forward, but not the object, but a pointer to it, that way you could access it and change its value for every class at the same time

Comment: a global variable, like a singleton, has the problem that it only needs to be initialized once. I need a way to ensure the mapping is recalculated at every entry point (which option 1 would do, but like I said, this would only be my last resort)

Comment: ah yes sorry, i got confused, anyways, i think the pointer would be a good solution here?